# Push new version of project to github

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a github repository where a project - lets call it myProject - is stored. The last commit was in 2013.

The developer who worked on this project before I did, did not use github.
Now I am going to work on myProject and I got a version of this project with big differences (like a new directory structure) from the master-version on github.

Is there any chance to push the new version to github using the existing repository and without deleting the existing branches?

Comment: What happens if you just push? Branches are independent from each other. If you commit something to master and push this, all other branches stay as they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check status by

```
/project$ git status
```

you can add all new directory by this command

```
/project$ git add *
```

Than again check project status you get the new  files which are added.

than push project directory

I hope this is help you.